# Social Services - Legal Jurisdiction of Child Abroad

Tags: international, jurisdiction, children, local-authorities

Does the child care department of social services have the legal right to interviene with a child that has a legal domicile (and juristiction) from another country?

For the sake of argument:

```
Child A is born in Germany.
Parent B takes Child A to the United Kingdom for a short holiday.
Person C makes a baseless, malicious phone call to United Kingdom social 
services regarding Parent B's capacity to care for Child A.
United Kingdom social services remove Child A from Parent B's care for a short time.
```

In the example above, did United Kingdom social services have the legal right to interviene or not?

Thank you,

KA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**

Anyone present in the U.K. Is subject to the laws of the U.K.